# how to get internet date and time in command or in javascript

Tags: javascript, c

I want to capture internet date and time from a batchfile  while starting and shutting down my pc
I tried javascript and cmd but it giving me my pc's current date and time
If i change it, it is giving me changed one not original

Comment: You need a ntp client

Comment: how to get ntp client

Comment: what is Internet date ?

Comment: for e.g. if I set computer time 8.27pm then javascript or command line gives me 8.27pm but I need correct time 9.29pm

Answer (score 0):

Under windows (Vista or newer), there is an integrated NTP client that can be used to get the current date and time from an NTP server.

If you just want to keep track of the times the batch file was executed, you could write the server response to a log file like this:

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:us.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:1 >> log.txt
```